# Using clone on multicore machine

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, multiprocessing, multicore

I am creating a number of threads equal to the number of cores of my machine using clone().
Can I be sure that each thread created will be run on a different core ,simultaneously
?
thanks

Comment: Read about [processor affinity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_affinity). Then do some searches in your favorite search engine.

Comment: `clone` creates a new *process*, unless you're passing it the flag `CLONE_THREAD`. In both cases, you can use [`sched_setaffinity`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setaffinity.2.html)